# How to handle gcc link options(like whole-archive, --allow-multiple-definition) in CMake？

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have a demo project and it's `structure` like as below:

```
top_dir 
    CMakeLists.txt 
    sub_dir1 
        CMakeLists.txt 
    sub_dir2 
        CMakeLists.txt
```

`top_dir/sub_dir1/CMakeLists.txt` used to build `lib1` by using `add_library(lib1 ...)`, 
`top_dir/sub_dir2/CMakeLists.txt` used to build `exe1` with linking `lib1` by `target_link_library(exe1 lib1)`.

And the content of top_dir/CMakeLists.txt is as below:

```
add_subdirectory(sub_dir2) 
add_subdirectory(sub_dir1)
```

Normally, when build target `exe1`, cmake will check `dependency` so `lib1` will be built before building `exe1`. The problem is I am transfering an existed makefile project into CMake, and there are many `gcc link options`, like `"whole-archive ... no-whole-archive, allow-mutiple-definition"`, if use like `target_link_library(exe1 "-Wl, --whole-archive ../sub_dir1/liblib1.a --no-whole-archive")`(The form like this, and this may not work, it just a e.g.), cmake seem don't built `lib1` any more. Is there any way i can use `target_link_library` like `target_link_library(exe1 "-Wl, --whole-archive ../sub_dir1/liblib1.a")` and cmake link dependency checking still work, or other way i can transfer these gcc link options into cmake?

Comment: Option `--whole-archive` is a *switch*, it doesn't need to be combined into *single argument* with futher library file and `--no-whole-archive` option. Such a way, library file is a *separate* argument to the linker, and it will be generated automatically when you use **library target**: `target_link_libraries(exe1 "-Wl,-whole-archive" lib1 "-Wl,-no-whole-archive")`. (Quotes are used only for cleareness, they can be safetly omited).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I mean `target_link_libraries(exe1 "-Wl,-whole-archive" lib1, lib2, lib3... "-Wl,-no-whole-archive")`, not just one lib.

Comment: So, enumerate all lib **targets** between plain options: `target_link_libraries(exe1 "-Wl,-whole-archive" lib1 lib2 lib3 "-Wl,-no-whole-archive")`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, i knew how to use it, because the makefile project already existed, and the gcc option existed. My question actually is  use target_link_library like target_link_library(exe1 "-Wl, --whole-archive ../sub_dir1/liblib1.a -Wl, --no-whole-archive") `and cmake link dependency checking still work`

Comment: When you use library **target** in `target_link_libraries`, then dependency checking works. It is stated in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for your replying, i have solved the problem. In my demo, i should use `-Wl, --whole-archive lib1 -Wl, --no-whole-archive` rather than `-Wl, --whole-archive ../sub_dir1/liblib1.a -Wl, --no-whole-archive`. :-)

Comment: This is what I wrote in the my first comment:)

Comment: @Tsyvarev, sorry for misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, you can re-edit your comment as an answer and i will accept it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments for `target_link_libraries` are going into the resulted command line in the same order they appears. Whenever **target name** is used as argument, *path to target's output* is used in resulted command line. So, you may use library target whenever you need path to that library in the command line:

```
target_link_libraries(exe1 -Wl,--whole-archive lib1 -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

Such a way a target-level dependency between executable *exe1* and library *lib1* is automatically deduced by CMake, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The next hack permits to locally define the flags  to the library to which you want to apply the flags, without modifying all exe link flags :

```
add_library(lib1_internal STATIC lib1.cpp)
add_library(lib1 STATIC dummy.cpp) # dummy.cpp is an empty file

target_link_libraries(lib1  PRIVATE -Wl,--whole-archive lib1_internal -Wl,--no-whole-archive )  

....

target_link_libraries(exe1 lib1)
```